# Problems creating downloadable word document in browser

Tags: javascript, html, browser, ms-word

I've been following this guide to create a word document from HTML in the browser:

http://www.effectiveui.com/blog/2015/02/23/generating-a-downloadable-word-document-in-the-browser/

Which works great, but has nothing about adding images. How do you do this?

Comment: Like the post said... if you create an html document with or without images and change the extension to .doc Word can open the file and can render the images in the `<img />` tags.

Comment: I've tried changing the extension to .doc and the images still do no render, just get a blank box where they should be. I'm using data uris as the source as the images are drawn from graph SVGs on the page